# How to set state in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to import Wordpress categories from .cvs file. I'm writing a simple app in react and I've got a function:

```
componentDidUpdate( prevProps, prevState ) {
    let that = this
    
    if (prevState.syncStatus !== this.state.syncStatus && this.state.syncStatus == 'posts') {    
        row_terms.forEach( (element, inx) => {
            let parent = that.state.parent_id;
            let _terms = element.split('>')
            _terms = _terms.map(function(e){return e.trim();});
            const total  = _terms.length
        
            _terms.forEach( (_term, index) => {
                addCategory(_term, that.state.parent_id).then(result => {
                    let term_id
        
                    if( result.code && result.code == 'term_exists' ) {
                        term_id = result.data.resource_id
                    } else {
                        term_id = result.id
                    }
        
                    if ( ( 1 + index ) === total ) {
                        categories.push(term_id)
                    } else {
                        that.setState({parent_id: term_id})
                    }
                })
                
            })
        })
    }
}
```

and addCategory:

```
import WooCommerce from './woocommerce'

async function addCategory(name, parent) {
    console.log('parent', parent)
    try {
        return await WooCommerce.postAsync('products/categories', {name: name, parent: parent}).then(result => {
            return JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        return e
    }

}
export default addCategory
```

and initial value is set

```
constructor(props) {
    super()
    this.state = {
        parent_id: 0,
    }
}
```

I want to add cateogories one after another because I need to set parent_id for categories that are children. So when it adds a category and the condition

```
if ( ( 1 + index ) === total ) {
```

is not met I want to set parent_id and then use it in next iteration. But it doesn't work.

When I use

```
console.log(that.state.parent_id)
```

after

```
that.setState({parent_id: term_id})
```

It prints correct value.

When i run my app it prints 0 ( console.log in addCategory() ) for all categories before any request is made.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't need to use `componentDidUpdate` – it tends to be a sign of using React in a non-Reacty way.

Comment: Either way, the problem here is that `setState` is asynchronous; the parent id change hasn't propagated to your component's state when you try to read it in the loop. Why does it need to be in your state in the first place?

Comment: React state is const, and state updates are asynchronous, so for the duration of the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method `this.state.parent_id` will remain the same. It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do, but I agree, it doesn't seem that this parent id value needs to be stored in state.

Comment: Consider isolating your fetching function to make it atomic. Right now you basically mix fetch - and render cycles; not only readability suffers, but also there are some weird bugs here. For example, what will you do if the last request actually returns _before_ some of the rest?

Comment: I agree with the comments above but a tip, if you ever find yourself in the scenario where you want to set a state based on props that change, you can use getDerivedStateFromProps. The return value of that function will set the state.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.forEach()` isn't aware of the asynchronicity of `addCategory`; you'll either have to chain all of those `then`s, or preferably just use `async`/`await` and plain old for loops, which can be used with `await` without extra hoops to jump through.

Assuming you want to loop through all of the `row_terms` and process them, you'll also need to `await` on those promises...

```
const categories = [];
const promises = row_terms.map(async (element) => {
  const terms = element.split(">").map((e) => e.trim());
  const total = terms.length;
  let parent = null;
  for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    const term = terms[i];
    const result = await addCategory(term, parent);
    const term_id = result.code && result.code === "term_exists" ? result.data.resource_id : result.id;
    if (i === total - 1) {
      categories.push(term_id);
    } else {
      parent = term_id;
    }
  }
});
await Promise.all(promises);
```